# Allow tags to be clickable showing jobs that also have those tags

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, stack-overflow-jobs

Companies post what technologies they use via the tags feature.  Feature request, allow the tag to be clickable showing me other jobs / companies who also are tagged with that technology.

Benefit of this, potential candidate sees a job he / she is interested in with the tag reporting services.  Notices the company may not be located where he / she is.  Wants to find other jobs who also work on reporting services.  By clicking the tag other companies are shows that have this technology stack.

[image]

PS: This works in search jobs but not search companies.  **I don't know why these two tabs work so differently!**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thank you for the report, Jon! :)

This is fixed, clicking the tags listed on the company search results would now take the user to company search filtered by that particular tag.

Answer (score 0):

We all agree it's a good suggestion, we just don't have the bandwidth (and it's always been that way). But it's on our internal feature request list now.